# REST Service-to-Service communication contract classes

Tags: architecture, microservices, integration

Given two systems A and B that communicate with a Request-Response protocol (REST services).

Where should the entities representing the request and response bodies reside?
N.B.: The entities above represent the contract of these two classes.

My idea is to have only these classes (entities) in their own Maven project, which is checked into a repository of their own and being released (following semantic versioning) as a Maven package.

The two systems then would declare said package as a dependency and use these classes for their controllers.
This results in the said package being the single source of truth for these data models.
(What I am trying to achieve with this is something similar to having your protobuf files in a repository of their own, which can be used by both systems.)

Does this way have any drawbacks I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's a great idea to publish client libraries for each of your systems.

The only thing I would change is to make two. One for system A's request and response schema and another for System B's. That way you increment the version when there's been a change to the schema and clients can only use the one they need.

I keep the client library in source control together with the API whose schema it represents, rather than in a separate repository. Then it's extracted during CI and published when there are changes.

As for drawbacks, I separate my schema entities into a separate project even if I'm not planning on publishing client libraries. So the only drawback is however much effort I spend on the publishing. YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Actually both schemas are the same for the two systems, one system uses the request schemas and the other the response schemas.